# How to improve electron app logging to file system, in a secured way?

Tags: logging, electron, desktop-application, slack, viber

We have a desktop app which is written using electron framework, we are logging information into file system like

```
1) Verbose logs (verbose.txt)
2) N/W calls (sync.txt)
3) User information with redaction (info.txt)

We are using log4js for file rotation.

Our concern is, most of the information is readable and decodable easily. 

**Question -**
   
 1. Is there a way to encrypt in such a way that only our technical team can decode it or is there a better way to manage logs?
 2. How do popular apps like, slack, teams and viber etc, manage there logging? How do they hide it?
```

Comment: Why would you want to hide logs? If the data is that valuable that you need to hide it, you're most likely doing something wrong. What would you need to hide? Secret internals of your application? If so, why do you log them? Most applications I know of use plain text files for logging if any, since no sensitive data but only diagnostics should be logged anyway. Also, I assume that MS Teams for example rather uses telemetry (i.e. directly sending diagnostic data to the software's vendor), but that introduces a whole lot of privacy concerns.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner, the reason we want to obfuscate from the user is, we do not want him to know our app internals, like API urls, signatures, flow etc. But we do collect logs on user concern.

Comment: Well, *someone*, eventually, will figure out your API URLs nonetheless. If they are savvy enough to care about technical internals, they will figure out a way. Spying on (encrypted) network traffic of a machine you control isn't hard at all. What I wanted to say was that you shouldn't care about logs exposing something because everything that could potentially be exposed by logs should be secured accordingly, even (!) if the logs are obfuscated or encrypted. Proposal: Why not remove the hostname/IP address from the logs and simply log the API path, not the complete URL?

Comment: Okay, got what you're saying, its better to remove sensitive info as you say instead of protecting it.

Thank you.